# Quartz.Net Trigger on Certain Days at a Given Time

Tags: .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I want to schedule Quartz.Net to run on a number of weekdays at a given time on each day. The schedule should run forever.

For example:

- Monday @ 12:00
- Thursday @ 12:00
- Saturday @ 12:00

I have the following configuration but it doesn't honour time, every time produced is 00:00 albeit it is on the correct day.

```
DateTimeOffset off = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.Day, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().
    WithIdentity("Test").
    WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x =>
        x.InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc).
        WithIntervalInHours(24).
        OnDaysOfTheWeek(process.RunAtDays)).
    StartAt(off).
    Build();
```

The output from this looks like:

- 01/10/2014 @ 00:00
- 08/10/2014 @ 00:00
- 15/10/2014 @ 00:00

I have tried various combinations to get this working with no luck so far.

I believe the equivalent cron configuration would be:

```
"0 00 12 ? * MON,THU,SAT"
```

But I need the values to be configurable by an end user.

Answer (score 4):

After a good few hours playing with values I believe I have the right combination to complete the task. I needed to set `StartingDailyAt()` to be the time I wanted to repeat on. The finished code looks like:

```
DateTimeOffset off = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.Day, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().
    WithIdentity("Test").
    WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x =>
        x.InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc).
        WithIntervalInHours(24).
        OnDaysOfTheWeek(process.RunAtDays).
        StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourMinuteAndSecondOfDay(12, 0, 0))).
    StartAt(off).
    Build();
```